# How to implode and foreach get

Tags: php, foreach, implode

I try to take each "name" and send it to my database for verification
the problem is that I can't take each one and go through the foreach

```
$name = $this->UserSkills->where('id', session()->get('id'))->first();
print_r($name) // return Array ( 
                          [id] => 5 
                          [user] => 15 
                          [name] => name,name1,name2,name3,name4
                         )

$name = implode(",", $name['name']);

foreach($name as $row) {
    $setname[] = $this->checkName->getIDbyName($row['name']);
}

$setname = implode(",", $setname);

$data['id_name'] = $setname;
```

finally I want him back

```
echo $data['id_name'] // return: 1,4,8,367, etc...
```

Comment: You can't have a `foreach` over a string. Did you mean `explode()` instead of `implode()` ??

Comment: I'm trying to get an ID by name. how to send each check name with ```$ this-> checkName-> getIDbyName ($ row ['name']); ``` then return all the verified names to me, ie return all ID separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first usage of `implode` is incorrect, you need `explode` to take a string and make it into an array.

```
<?php

$name = $this->UserSkills->where('id', session()->get('id'))->first();

$name = explode(",", $name['name']);

foreach($name as $row) {
    $setname[] = $this->checkName->getIDbyName($row);
}

$setname = implode(",", $setname);

$data['id_name'] = $setname;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `$name['name']` returns `string` not `array`, So you need to `explode()` not to `implode()`.

Try something like this:

```php
$name = $this->UserSkills->where('id', session()->get('id'))->first();
print_r($name); // return Array ([id] => 5, [user] => 15, [name] => name,name1,name2,name3,name4)

$names = explode(',', $name['name']); // return Array (0 => name, 1 => name1, 2 => name2, 3 => name3, 4 => name4)

foreach ($names as $row) {
    $setname[] = $this->checkName->getIDbyName($row['name']);
}

$setname = implode(",", $setname); // return 1,4,8,367, etc
$data['id_name'] = $setname; // return 1,4,8,367, etc

echo $data['id_name']; // return 1,4,8,367, etc
```

Assuming that your `getIDbyName()` return `ID` as `integer`